# Beautiful Soup - How to find tags after a specific item in HTML?

Tags: beautifulsoup

I need to find tags after a specific item on a website. So, is there a way to skip the tag objects until this specific one, then find the matching ones to given criteria? I need all `p` with class `XYZ` after the `div` with class `ABC`.

```
response = requests.get(url).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response)
items = soup.find_all('p', {'class': 'MessageTextSize  js-message-text message-text'})  # only return the ones after the div with class of "Text 2"
```

**Edit:** You can see a sample code block below which is part `response`. The aim is finding the last two paragraphs (`Text 3` & `Text 4`) despite the first one (`Text 1`) also has the same `p` `class` with them. So, I need to look for the parameter of `find_all` function after the `Text 2` (class `MessageTextSize  js-message-text message-text`).

```
<div class="js-message-text-container">
    <p class="MessageTextSize  js-message-text message-text" data-aria-label-part="0">Text 1</p>
</div>


<div class="js-message-text-container">
    <p class="MessageTextSize MessageTextSize--jumbo js-message-text message-text" data-aria-label-part="0">Text 2</p>
</div>


<div class="js-message-text-container">
    <p class="MessageTextSize  js-message-text message-text" data-aria-label-part="0">Text 3</p>
</div>

<div class="js-message-text-container">
    <p class="MessageTextSize  js-message-text message-text" data-aria-label-part="0">Text 4</p>
</div>
```

p.s. `bs4` version is `4.8.1`, which is the latest release.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Can you please include your code and what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: Please see the edited OP as I have added a sample code and explanation. @BittoBennichan

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of `response`?

Comment: Please see the updated OP. @JackFleeting

Comment: will you know the value of "text 2" ?

Comment: @talha06 Thanks for the edit. Please see my answer.

Comment: No, unfortunately, I will not know it. @QHarr

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use a custom function (or a lambda expression) inside find_all. The following is self-explanatory (IMO).

```
result = soup.find_all(
    lambda x: x.name == 'p' and
    'XYZ' in x.get('class', '') and
    x.find_previous('div', class_='ABC')
)
```

Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = """
<p class="XYZ">Text 1</p>
<p class="XYZ">Text 2</p>
<div class="ABC"></div>
<p class="XYZ">Text 3</p>
<p class="XYZ">Text 4</p>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
result = soup.find_all(
    lambda x: x.name == 'p' and
    'XYZ' in x.get('class', '') and
    x.find_previous('div', class_='ABC')
)
print(result)
```

Output

```
[<p class="XYZ">Text 3</p>, <p class="XYZ">Text 4</p>]
```

**EDIT**

- `MessageTextSize js-message-text message-text` represents three classes, not one.
- `x.get('class', '')` returns a list of classes -

  `['MessageTextSize', 'js-message-text', 'message-text']`
- In your particular case, you have to target a `p` tag not a `div`, if I understood correctly.

So, you have to use

```
result = soup.find_all( 
    lambda x: x.name == 'p' and 
    'MessageTextSize js-message-text message-text' in ' '.join(x.get('class', ''))
    and x.find_previous('p', class_='MessageTextSize MessageTextSize--jumbo js-message-text message-text') 
)
```

**Ref:**

- [find_previous()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all-previous-and-find-previous)
- [Function as filter](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#a-function)

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but getting `TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable` for the line starts with `'XYZ' in ....`.

Comment: @talha06 Sorry my bad. Forgot to handle `<p>` tags without class. `'XYZ' in x.get('class', '')` would work fine. See my edit.

Comment: Please see my edited original post in order to evaluate the following command which returns simply an empty resultset: `result = soup.find_all(
        lambda x: x.name == 'p' and
                  'MessageTextSize js-message-text message-text' in x.get('class', '') and
                  x.find_previous('div', class_='MessageTextSize MessageTextSize--jumbo js-message-text message-text')
    )`

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this should work:

```
item = soup.select_one('p[class*="MessageTextSize--jumbo"]')
sibs = item.parent.find_next_siblings()
for sib in sibs:
   print(sib.text.strip())
```

Output:

> Text 3
>
> Text 4

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, but actually I am not looking for the next siblings. The ones after the searched one (`Text 2`), which are `Text 3` and `Text 4`, do have different classes.